# Expo FileSystem vs AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, filesystems, mobile-application, asyncstorage

I'm developing a mobile app with React Native and Expo managed workflow. The app is supposed to serve as a song book with lyrics to songs and hymns. All of the lyrics are stored in Firebase' Firestore database and clients can load them in app. However, I also want to implement offline functionality, where all of the lyrics are stored on the user's device.

When researching how to achieve this, I came across two packages: [Expo FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) and [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/). I'm wondering which one of these is a better fit for my application. I tried to find some comparisons but couldn't find anything relevant. Can anyone advise me on this?

I've read that AsyncStorage has a cap of 6MB of data you can store. I did some math and found out that if I have a double headroom for my data, the total size would be around 2MB. *(lyrics for one song which I have stored in .txt file are between 500-900 bytes, there will be around 1000 songs. So if I take 1000 * 800 bytes = 0.7 MB and if I double the number of songs, which will probably not happen, it's around 1.5 MB)*

The songs are stored as objects in database, I used the .txt file just for size calculations, so I think the final size will be even smaller.

So, is there anyone who can tell me the difference between FileSystem and AsyncStorage and maybe advise me on which one to choose for my project?

Comment: Heres a viable option as-well (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) give it look. Its ~30x faster than AsyncStorage and is synchronous

Comment: (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/issues/323) this gives you more info on memory limits, better than async storage aswell

Comment: wow, thanks, that looks really nice, it looks so much better than AsyncStorage :o the speed comparison is mindblowing :o thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store them yourself, you can access them directly from Firestore local persistence.

From the Firestore docs:
This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

Full docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).

Also a nice tutorial here [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329).